# How to integrate Paystack to my Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel

So far all I have been getting is "Class paystack not found". I'm using Laravel 5.7, even after placing the Paystack provider code into the app.php file, and I try to publish, it says:

> Class 'Unicodeveloper\Paystack\PaystackServjceProvider not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may not have installed it yet? Try running:

```
composer require unicodeveloper/laravel-paystack
```

From the project root. Then do a:

```
composer update
```

Then you should be able to use it.

More instructions can be found on the [github page for the laravel paystack](https://github.com/unicodeveloper/laravel-paystack) project.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code below  in your composer.json file present in ur root folder

"unicodeveloper/laravel-paystack": "1.0.*"

And the run composer update. After creat your paystack.php file in /config directory. Remember to create your controller and route. Also don't forget to register ur webhook and callback in your paystack dashboard